# jqGrid/asp.net mvc 3: setGridWidth(width) does not work in PartialView?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, jqgrid

i am using a jqgrid in my asp.net mvc 3 application. I noticed that changing the width does not work when u use the jqGrid as partialview?

```
jQuery("#targetGrid").setGridWidth(width);
```

it works fine as a non partialview though?

Comment: Perhaps that ID doesn't exist? Or is called at an incorrect time? Or there is some unexpected CSS that is interfering?

Answer (score 0):

Okay there could be three solutions i would like to tell you and i'm not sure about any of those. I can't test them now(not at work).

First add width to your jqgrid parameters.

check this [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options). This has a plenty of options for setting width or rows, columns and others. Search for width, you will get plenty of options.

Second you can specify the table width where you are binding the data.

Third you can make changes in ui.jqGrid.css and specify the width from there itself.